# Does Alexa's crawler need a robots.txt on each sub domain?

Tags: robots.txt, alexa

I have a robots.txt on my `www` site. Do I also need one on other sites like my `app` and `forums` sites?

Alexa audit keeps finding bad links, missing tags, and other "errors" on my vanilla forums site even though the `www` site's robots.txt says to ignore specific directories that are on my app and forum sites.

Comment: It's not just Alexa, every crawler needs a robots.txt on each and every subdomain on which you want to control crawling.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to remember is that example.com, www.example.com, sub-domain.example.com, even HTTP versus HTTPS are all different sites.

Robots.txt cannot reference other sites, it is only for the site it resides upon. So for any sub-domain you will need a robots.txt just for that site.